# Picture Upload Trouble

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, image-uploading

This is my upload Action :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult addcar(Models.vehicule model)
    {
        ViewBag.cat = new SelectList(entity.categorie, "Idcat", "Nom");
        ViewBag.mark = new SelectList(entity.marque, "id", "nom");      
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
// Upload Function begin
            var destinationFolder = Server.MapPath("/Content/Vpic");
            foreach (string name in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = Request.Files[name];
                if (postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = model.Matv;
                    var path = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, fileName + ".jpg");
                    postedFile.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }
// upload function end

            model.Idag = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
            entity.vehicule.AddObject(model);
            entity.SaveChanges();
            TempData["Resultat"] = "L'ajout de véhicule a reussi";
            return RedirectToAction("GesV", "Agence");
        }
        else
            return View();

    }
```

And this is my view :

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("addcar", "Agence", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "search_form", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

I have used this same function already in other code it works fine here i dont know whi it dosen't work, The reste of action works fine but the photo is not uploaded

Comment: What does your View look like? Are you including the atribute enctype = "multipart/form-data"  on your form tag in the view?

Comment: yeah, i included enctype

Comment: Well the only thing different that I see is that I set an explicit parameter on my action for the file along with the model: public ActionResult addcar(Models.vehicule model, HttpPostedFileBase file)... otherwise I don't see any difference

Comment: Have you checked the file size? By default there is a limit of 5MB on the browser for file upload size...maybe it's too big?

Comment: i fix it, i have removed `@` before `enctype` and it works  so fine

Comment: Awesome, I figured it was something small glad my example pointed that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your View look like? Are you including the atribute enctype = "multipart/form-data" on your form tag in the view?

Verify @ sign, not needed on enctype